# Based on configured schedule the given trigger will never fire Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

Below is the code,

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger().withIdentity(job.getTriggerName(), job.getGroupName())                    
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(new CronExpression(cronExpression)).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(remoteTimezone)).withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())                 
            .startAt(startDate)
            .endAt(endDate)                 
            .build();
```

Below are the logs,

```
[11-28 15:30:00,906] [pool-1-thread-1] [INFO:QuartzJob:99] job.getStartTimes() - 10:00,11:00,12:00
[11-28 15:30:00,908] [pool-1-thread-1] [INFO:QuartzJob:105] dateValue - Sat Nov 28 15:30:00 IST 2020
[11-28 15:30:00,909] [pool-1-thread-1] [INFO:QuartzJob:105] dateValue - Sat Nov 28 16:30:00 IST 2020
[11-28 15:30:00,910] [pool-1-thread-1] [INFO:QuartzJob:105] dateValue - Sat Nov 28 17:30:00 IST 2020
[11-28 15:30:00,913] [pool-1-thread-1] [INFO:QuartzJob:130] mins --- 30
[11-28 15:30:00,913] [pool-1-thread-1] [INFO:QuartzJob:131] hours --- 15,16,17
[11-28 15:30:00,913] [pool-1-thread-1] [INFO:QuartzJob:132] Timezone startDate --- Sat Nov 28 15:30:00 IST 2020
[11-28 15:30:00,913] [pool-1-thread-1] [INFO:QuartzJob:133] Timezone endDate --- Sat Nov 28 17:30:00 IST 2020
[11-28 15:30:00,913] [pool-1-thread-1] [INFO:QuartzJob:137] Generated cronExpression for the Job is - 0 30 15,16,17 * * ?
```

Job start times values are in GMT which are converted to IST and Cron Expression is made.
But Getting the below error,

```
[11-28 15:30:00,936] [pool-1-thread-1] [ERROR:JobExecutor:71] org.quartz.SchedulerException: Based on configured schedule, the given trigger '2020-11-28-DUMMY_JOB_TEST-Jobs.2020-11-28-DUMMY_JOB_TEST-Trigger' will never fire.
```

**Dont understand why this is happening ?**
with .startNow() also getting the same Error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is really weird. Can you share your app or a simplified version of it? I can try to analyze what is going on using my local QuartzDesk installation and share the results here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your start and dates are the same:

`Timezone startDate --- Sat Nov 28 15:30:00 IST 2020 Timezone endDate --- Sat Nov 28 17:30:00 IST 2020`

they differ only in a few hours, but the quartz scheduler works in a way that the end date must be at least one day after the start date.
You may try testing by removing `.endAt(endDate)`, it should work.